# "Status" return of a WMI feature is empty

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, wmi, wmi-query

I am converting a Installer Programm from VBS into a C# programm. 
In this installation i have to activate some windows features with DISM.

```
"cmd.exe", "/C Dism /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:WAS-ProcessModel"
```

I activated them in this way. And when i check them manualy with

```
dism /online /get-featureinfo /featurename:WAS-ProcessModel
```

in the command prompt, then i get the information of the Feature, including the Status. (Status : Activated)

But when i try to get it via my programm the Status return is just empty.

Here the relevant part of my programm:

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\ROOT\\cimv2");

//create object query
ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OptionalFeature Where Name=\"WAS-ProcessModel\"");

//create object searcher
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

//get a collection of WMI objects
ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();

//enumerate the collection.
foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
{
    // access properties of the WMI object

    Console.WriteLine("Caption : {0}" + Environment.NewLine + "Status : {1}", m["Caption"], m["Status"]);

}
```

The return of this is:

```
Caption : Prozessmodell
Status :
```

How can i get the status of the feature?
Am i doing something completely wrong? I am new to this DISM/ WMI things so maybe it is just some basic thing i did wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [documentation for the `Status` property on the `Win32_OptionalFeature` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee309383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> "This property is NULL."

You need the `InstallState` property instead:

> Identifies the state of the optional feature. The following states are
>   possible:
>
> Enabled (1)
>
> Disabled (2)
>
> Absent (3)
>
> Unknown (4)

You can add those to an enum, and use that to display the output:

```
public enum InstallState
{
    Enabled = 1,
    Disabled = 2,
    Absent = 3,
    Unknown = 4
}
```

…

```
foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
{ 
  var status = (InstallState)Enum.Parse(typeof(InstallState), m["InstallState"].ToString());

  Console.WriteLine("Caption : {0}" 
            + Environment.NewLine + "Status : {1}", m["Caption"], status);
}
```

This then returns:

> Caption : Process Model
>
> Status : Enabled

Comment: Wow, Thank you for your quick help!
And yes, this solved my problem :D